# Is it possible to check who approved pull request that has already been merged?

Tags: github, pull-request

Does github store a history of all the activity for a given repository? I'd like to check, who approved a specific pull request, that had already been merged.

Comment: Pull requests aren't a Git feature, but rather a GitHub, Bitbucket, etc., feature, so you need to use the appropriate interface. On GitHub you'll see this sort of thing if you look at the PR, I think (the last N years that I've used GitHub we weren't forcing people to get approval first).